# Vertical stacking of line plots using ChartJs library sharing same x axis

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I want to have three LineCharts below each other. They are sharing same x-axis (time). I was able to create this:
[image]

However, it is very useless to have x-axis on the top and middle chart. I would prefer not to display the x-axis for the top and middle. When I tried it, I got this:
[image]

But as you can see, the last grid for 12AM is not visible for the top and middle chart, and the grids are not aligned (it looks weird). Each chart is rendered as a separate component using React.

Here are my `TimelinePlot` component which is rendering each LineChart (sorry for the mess, but I did not yet refactor it):

```
    import React from 'react';
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import { GetColors } from '../../utils/PlotDescriptionHelper';

class TimelinePlot extends React.Component {
  MapPropsToData(props) {
    const colors = GetColors(props.series.length);
    return props.series.map((dataset, index) => {
      return {
        label: dataset.name,
        data: dataset.data,
        borderWidth: 1,
        fill: false,
        borderColor: colors[index],
        //pointBackgroundColor: 'rgb(255,255,255)',
      };
    });
  }

  MapPropsToOptions(props) {
    return {
      elements: {
        point: {
          radius: 0,
        },
      },
      legend: {
        // display: props.showLegend,
        position: 'top',
        align: 'end',
      },
      scales: {
        yAxes: [
          {
            ticks: props.yAxisTicks,
            scaleLabel: {
              display: true,
              labelString: props.yAxisName + props.yAxisUnit,
            },
          },
        ],
        xAxes: [
          {
            type: 'time',
            // position: props.xAxisPosition,
            time: {
              parser: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm',
              tooltipFormat: 'll HH:mm',
            },
            // scaleLabel: {
            //   display: true,
            //   //labelString: 'Date',
            // },
            ticks: {
              min: props.xAxisStart,
              max: props.xAxisEnd,
              //display: true,
              display: props.xAxisDisplay,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    };
  }

  render() {
    const dataset = { datasets: this.MapPropsToData(this.props) };
    return (
      <div className='measurement-row'>
        <Line
          data={dataset}
          options={this.MapPropsToOptions(this.props)}
          position='absolute'
          height='15%'
          width='80%'
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And here is the render method of the parent using `TimelinePlot` component:

```
render() {
    var plots = Object.keys(this.state.timeSeries).map((key, index) => {
      return (
        <TimelinePlot
          key={key + index}
          series={this.state.timeSeries[key]}
          yAxisName={FirstLetterToUpper(key)}
          yAxisUnit={MapKeyToUnit(key)}
          xAxisDisplay={index === Object.keys(this.state.timeSeries).length - 1}
          xAxisPosition={index === 0 ? 'top' : 'bottom'}
          xAxisStart={this.state.startTime}
          xAxisEnd={this.state.endTime}
          showLegend={index === 0}
          yAxisTicks={MapYAxisTicks(key)}
        />
      );
    });

    return (
      <div className='width-90'>
        <TimelineDashboardHeader />
        <div className='dashboard__column'>{plots}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can you add your react code as well?

Comment: sure! I edited my question

Comment: Do you want to have a common y axis too for them?

Comment: no, I want to have 3 separate charts. They should be only stack on each other.

Comment: You can use some custom CSS for that. Not sure how this is related to `react` or `chartjs`. The behaviour is correct.

Comment: I tried to do it in css but only partial success. The thing what bother me the most is in the second picture. The top and middle have options for xAxes: `ticks:{
              min: 12AM,
              max: 12AM (next day),
              display: false}` . it shows all ticks from 12AM but not the last one for 12AM of next day. It is very ugly

Comment: You would want to keep everything `display:false` in x-axisfor top and middle chart. If you apply different ticks for them, then obviously this is the problem which you are facing.

You should only apply ticks to the bottom chart.

Comment: I came up with different solution. I set `fontSize:1` for ticks in xAxes. Apparently, I cannot set `fontSize:0` because then the grid will completely disappear. It isn't perfect but with size 1, you cannot recognise. But honestly, it should be possible to stack charts on each other to share x axes but have independent y axes.